# Use cardinal notation to denote the last element in a finite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In set theory, is it correct/okay/reasonable to denote the last element in a finite set using cardinal notation?

Example:

$$
X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{|X|}\}
$$

Comment: I usually say "Let the finite set $X$ be given by $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. I can't recall seeing $|X|$ used that way. I don't see a formal problem, but I had to think for a second to realize that it wasn't circular (you need to be careful with definitions which reference the object they are defining). So for readability's sake I would avoid it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as the last element in a set, since a set is in unordered collection of elements. But the notation you've used seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Arthur What alternative greek symbol do you suggest other than using n ? In my mathematical model I already used almost all English single word characters for other purposes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no last element of a set, because a set is unordered. If you want to talk about the "last element", there are two ways to do it:

- define the set as $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$, and then refer to $x_n$. This requires you to have already defined an order at the start, and it doesn't work well with other constructions of sets.
- use a **tuple** instead. A element of the set $X^n$ is an ordered collection of $n$ elements of $X$: we call this an "$n$-tuple". For instance, an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an ordered pair of the form $(x,y)$, where both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. In this case, you could make a note saying something like "We use subscripts to pick out elements of a tuple: for instance, $T_2$ is the second element of the tuple $T$. We also use $|T|$ to denote the length of $T$." Then you can go ahead and use $T_{|T|}$ without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, in short, the notation I used in my example is technically correct or its wrong/non-sense ?

Comment: @MichelGokan It's correct, but *only* if you specify that $X$ is the set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{|X|}\}$. If you don't, then it's meaningless. (And remember, sets *also* don't allow duplicates: if you want duplicates, then you will definitely want to use a tuple instead of a set.)